# Is there a way to backup a single ReliableCollection in service fabric?

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

I have three reliable collections defined in my StatefulService defined this way:

```
this.dataCount = 
      await StateManager.GetOrAddAsync<IReliableDictionary<string, int>>("count");

this.dataDictionary1 = 
     await StateManager
          .GetOrAddAsync<IReliableDictionary<string, ResourceElement>>
          ("data1");

this.dataDictionary2 = 
     await StateManager
          .GetOrAddAsync<IReliableDictionary<string, ResourceElement>>
          ("data2");
```

Now I would like to move collection **data2** (its contents) to a separate StatefulService and I am not sure how to proceed.

Ideally, I am looking for a mechanism that would allow me to backup **data2** (i don't mind if I have to add a method to my service) to a file and then resume the backup from that file into a different service.

Is there anything like this available?

Answer (score 0):

Backups work at the service partition level. The only way to create a backup of a single collection, is to have a stateful service with 1 partition that holds only that collection.

What you can do, is restore backup(s) of your old service (service 1) to a new service (service 2), that you create just for the purpose of moving data from the **data2** collection to another service (service 3). After that you delete service 2 and continue running service 3.